# UICollectionView move item and keep cell size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have different sized cells and I am trying to move a CollectionView Cell, and keep the moving/selected cells size moving to the new position.

I have made the [project](https://github.com/JCzz/ProfileToOverview) public on Github, let me know if you want to be added as collaborator?

I am sub classing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and have implemented the following:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext *)invalidationContextForInteractivelyMovingItems:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)targetIndexPaths withTargetPosition:(CGPoint)targetPosition previousIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)previousIndexPaths previousPosition:(CGPoint)previousPosition{

    UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext *context = [super
                                                          invalidationContextForInteractivelyMovingItems:targetIndexPaths
                                                          withTargetPosition:targetPosition
                                                          previousIndexPaths:previousIndexPaths
                                                          previousPosition:previousPosition];

    [self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:previousIndexPaths[0] toIndexPath:targetIndexPaths[0]];

    return context;
}
```

Also tried to implement this in the UICollectionViewController:

```
-(NSIndexPath *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)originalIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedIndexPath{
    if (originalIndexPath.section == proposedIndexPath.section) {
        return  proposedIndexPath;
    }else{
        return originalIndexPath;
    }
}
```

Do you know how to keep the size?

Comment: Are the size of your cells random or is it initialized relatively to the content ?

Comment: It is relative to the content. I got inspired from: http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/

Comment: Ok, so your problem is that your dropped view is not the same size as before you drag it ?

Comment: Right, the cell change size

Comment: Not so easy, right :-)

Comment: Yep I looked a bit to the tutorial, didn't take time to try it tho, I'll check that during the week if you're still stuck. Is it possible for you to put a github repo

Comment: Cool; I have updated the question with a link to the github project. Look for OverViewViewController & WidgetsFlowLayout.

Comment: The cells actually keep the same size for me, is this the expected result ? -> on launch : http://imgur.com/7AeuuJ4, after drag and drop : http://imgur.com/BhK4AEw

Comment: Hi and thanks for looking at it - I think I know what happened. I will get back with the solution. Hint; in moveItemAtIndexPath I am swapping items back to statring position - I am currently looking for detecting when I start dragging.

Comment: I am assuming you need to use the LayoutInvalidationContext in the layout subclass to ensure the sizes do not change, still not sure how. @chris-g Have you figured this out yet?

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem, the reason is you need call the delegate's moveItemAtIndexPath.

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext *)invalidationContextForInteractivelyMovingItems:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)targetIndexPaths withTargetPosition:(CGPoint)targetPosition previousIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)previousIndexPaths previousPosition:(CGPoint)previousPosition{

    UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext *context = [super
                                                          invalidationContextForInteractivelyMovingItems:targetIndexPaths
                                                          withTargetPosition:targetPosition
                                                          previousIndexPaths:previousIndexPaths
                                                          previousPosition:previousPosition];

    [self.collectionView.dataSource collectionView:self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:previousIndexPaths[0] toIndexPath:targetIndexPaths[0]];

    return context;
}
```